# Read every character in PDF into exact same location in a word file

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a scanned PDF file into an editable word file. I have managed to find an Ocr library that can read all the text characters and their location on the scanned PDF file. Since I have the co-ordinate of the location of each text character on the PDF, how do I place each character exactly where it was in the PDF but in the new word file

```
//import Iron Ocr library

using IronOcr;

//import Microsoft Office libraries 

using Microsoft.Office.Interop;

//programmatically create a new word file
Word.Application converted = new Word.Application();
//add a new word document 
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; 
converted.Document.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
//create a new instance of Iron Tesseract
var engine = new IronTesseract();
//get all the text characters from the pdf
var ocrResult = engine.Read("scanned.pdf");
//each ocr result contains all the text characters and their locations
foreach(var chr in ocrResult.Characters){
   //get the text character
    var character = chr.Text;
    //get the character location
    var X = chr.X;
    var Y = chr.Y;
    //write this character in the exact word file location,  how do I do that 
}
```

Comment: Good luck with that, Word works with _runs_, not positions

Comment: So technically there is no way I can programmatically create a new TextBox , set its location to the location of the same text character and then add it to the word file then repeat this for all characters

Comment: You can try it, and it _might_ look similar to the original, but it won't be editable. You would have a movable textbox for every character of a paragraph. That's unmaintainable.

Comment: @PMF, True using the TextBoxes will make the word file uneditable.

Comment: Is there a way I can move the editing cursor to that location in the word file then programmatically type the character in that position

Comment: It works in _runs_, that flow; just like the Word app does. Don't think you can program something much different than what you can do with Word. If you wanted to do this in the app, you could change the font size for every line end and then change the kerning between characters. Doing it programmatically would be an _interesting_ programming exercise, but you'd likely give up before you finish

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called GemBox.Document wich allows you to convert a PDF file to a docx file. Here is the [documentation](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-convert-pdf-to-docx/308) with an example

In your case, I guess you're using OCR because it's a scanned document, so I'm not sure that there is a library able to translate OCR to docx... But it's worth the try !

GemBox also have a PDF/OCR [module](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf).

Comment: Will give its try